# How can I add a new application to the Open With menu?

Tags: macos

How can I add an application to the Open With menu (shown after right-clicking) for a given file type, without making that file **always** open with that application?

In this specific instance, I'd like to the option to open an Web site location (.URL) file with TextEdit, while still defaulting to Safari.

I'm running OS 10.7.4.

Comment: If the program can open it, then it will add itself to that menu. Otherwise, it means it can't open it.

Comment: This seems to not always be true.  TextEdit can open URLs, but it is not in the "Open With" submenu.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

1. Add this to the CFBundleDocumentTypes array in `/Applications/TextEdit.app/Contents/Info.plist`:

   ```
   <dict>
       <key>CFBundleTypeExtensions</key>
       <array>
           <string>url</string>
       </array>
   </dict>
   ```
2. `/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/Support/lsregister -f /Applications/TextEdit.app/`
3. `killall Finder`
4. Change the default application back to Safari in Finder

If the application is signed, modifying an Info.plist [invalidates the code signature](https://superuser.com/questions/47504/if-mac-code-signing-is-tampered-with-what-might-fail). It also makes a few applications like TextEdit and WriteRoom crash on launch on 10.8.

Comment: Perhaps it's just my computer, but this does not work for me.  After following this procedure (to step 3), TextEdit is not available under "Open With" for .URL files.  Also, modifying Info.plist seems to cause TextEdit to crash in 10.7, too.

Comment: Is there a way to make this more general? E.g. I want my hex editor (currently HexFiend) as an option to open *every* goddamn file type including those not having a file extension...

Comment: @StevenLu: I made a Finder shortcut in BetterTouchTool to open the currently selected file in HexFiend.

Comment: Been struggling with this for a very long time.  @StevenLu's question is still valid, especially for editors, but being able to do it for the most common files is useful.  Repeating this exercise for `Visual Studio Code` I wasn't sure which `CFBundleTypeExtensions` group it belonged in.  I added the new extension just under `<string>txt</string>` but I'm not entirely sure if that's correct.  Regardless, it worked.  So far, no issues with breaking signatures either.

Comment: @Lri or to anyone who can answer:

I have questions about this part of Lri's answer: "If the application is signed, modifying ... crash on launch on 10.8." 
 
What are the consequences of having TextEdit (or another app) having an invalidated sig.?  Does it cause problems when attempting to update the app to a newer release? Or? 

Does step 2 (lsregister) resolve the problem of invalidating the code sig.?  What exactly does the lsregister command do? 

Does the problem with TextEdit/WriteRoom crashing still exist in more current releases such as macOS 12?

Answer (score 15):

Try selecting the file in the Finder and doing File > Get Info. From there you should be able to choose any application to open it with. Once you've opened that type of file in that application once, it *should* start appearing in the Open With menu.

**EDIT: The answer above does not work. Alternate suggestion:**

I felt bad that my prev answer was incorrect, so I googled around. I found [this tip](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20030730161311391) from Mac OS X Hints:

> - Control-click (or right-click) the app in question and select "Show Package   Contents"
> - Open the Contents folder in the app bundle. There you'll find a file called Info.plist. This is an XML property list that stores all sorts of information about the app.
> - Open the file with your favourite text editor. I recommend Hydra, but TextEdit will do just fine.
> - Search for something that looks like the following:
>
>   ```
>   <key>CFBundleTypeExtensions</key>
>   <array>
>       <string>txt</string>
>       <string>srt</string>
>       <string>suffix1</string>
>       <string>suffix2</string>
>       …
>   ```
>
>   and so forth, with the suffices the app is able to open contained within the tags. Then you simply delete [*or add --newtron*] the suffix for items you don't want [*or want*] the app to open.
> - Save the file, and close it (or quit the editor).

Comment: This does not seem to work.  In "Get Info", I can "Open With" the same applications as normal, or choose "Other".  If I choose "Other", I can choose from all applications, and either check or uncheck "Always Open With".  Even after opening the file once with TextEditor, it does not appear as an additional option in the "Open With" submenu.

Comment: Shoot, you're right. I will edit the answer to reflect this and update it with an alternate suggestion.

Comment: This updated answer doesn't work all by itself, even after a reboot.

Comment: Think this method worked in snow leopard..http://superuser.com/questions/222065/how-can-i-add-a-program-to-the-open-with-menu-on-a-mac

Comment: The amended instructions are the same as Lri's answer, but theirs is better because it has the `lsregister` and `killall Finder` forcing refresh immediately.

Answer (score 9):

newtron's second solution worked for me but only after I opened Terminal and executed the following command:

`/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/Support/lsregister -kill -r -domain local -domain system -domain user`

After restarting the system the desired app was in my "open with" context menu.

Thanks

Comment: This is also useful if you want to clear the list and start again. e.g. VMWare Fusion had placed entries somehow that where orphaned when the corresponding VM was deleted. Using this cleared the incorrect entries

Comment: Lri's steps in another answer (accepted solution) worked just fine for me.  Posting this in 2020 using MacOS Big Sur 11.0.

Answer (score 8):

Instead of opening the file with the context menu, you can also drag any file to any desired application while pressing <kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd> keys. This will force any app to **try** even if it thinks it can't do so. I use this all the time.

Comment: I just dragged an unknown document type to a text editor's app shortcut on the Dock without holding these key combinations and it worked.  These additional shortcut keys may no longer be needed.

Comment: This is the easiest answer. What an obscure keyboard shortcut though!

Answer (score 8):

You can add the option as a Service with Automator and then trigger it with a Hotkey from Keyboard Maestro.

1. Open `Automator` and select `Quick Action` document type (formerly `Service`)
2. Select `Files and Folders` in the top `Workflow receives selected` menu
3. Search for and select the `Open Finder Items` action.
4. Now select `TextEdit` in `Open with:`
5. Save the service with a name you want to see in the menus

You can now find this by:

- Right-clicking the file and searching near the bottom or in `Quick Actions`

[image]

OR

- Finder Menu > Services (with a file selected)

[image]

But you don't have to stop there!

I then made a Keyboard Maestro macro so I can just use a Hotkey to do it:
[image]

I got this idea from this site:
http://www.mactricksandtips.com/2013/05/add-open-with-textedit-or-any-other-app-to-right-click-menu-item.html

Comment: This is a great way of doing this, thank you very much!!

Comment: I use the service all the time but I forgot I made a macro to do this. Nothing like rediscovering a macro!

Comment: I've never used Automator before (or knew what it does), you've just opened a whole new world in OSX for me :)

Comment: This is the best answer. This applies to all file extensions, even when there is none. And it doesn't require maintenance and doesn't require messing with the terminal. 
Not that I'm against messing with the terminal, but for the common user it is best to avoid it ofcourse.

Comment: This is a very nice alternative. I did the Info.plist approach, but on MacOS 13 (at least), system integrity then prevents you from running the application (in my case, XnViewMP) at all. This approach is much more flexible, and doesn't make the system paranoid that someone has hacked an executable.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me : 
Right click your app and goto contents and open /Applications/*****.app/Contents/Info.plist

Open Plist in Xcode as SourceCode and then place this :

```
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeExtensions</key>
            <array>
                <string>jpeg</string>
                <string>jpg</string>
                <string>png</string>
                <string>gif</string>
            </array>
            <key>CFBundleTypeIconFile</key>
            <string>AutomatorApplet.icns</string>
            <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
            <string>AutomatorApplet.icns</string>
            <key>CFBundleTypeOSTypes</key>
            <array>
                <string>GIFf</string>
                <string>JPEG</string>
                <string>PNGf</string>
            </array>
            <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
            <string>Viewer</string>
        </dict>
```

I had 'AutomatorApplet.icns' in Resources Folder.

Comment: Please add what you tried to achieve by adding the dict entry. As your answer stands now, it doesn't use the example (.url) given in the question.

Answer (score -4):

Check out the [tech-recipes.com](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/2573/os_x_how_to_change_default_application_to_open_file_type/) for detailed instructions. As @Anriëtte pointed out the app should appear on the Open with menu if it can open the specific file.

Comment: This doesn't work for me because I don't want to change the default application which opens the file.  I just want an additional choice.