# how to move the 'New MacVim Buffer Here' menu into the main context menu?

Tags: macvim

If I right click on a file, I can open the file by clicking *Services* and then *New MacVim Buffer Here*:

[image]

However, this is a bit cumbersome.

How can I move the *New MacVim Buffer Here* menu action to be at the same level as the *Service* menu action?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a "clean" way to specifically move a single service item in the context menu.

What you can do is increase the amount of items allowed in the context menu before a submenu is created.

**In Terminal.app**:

```
defaults write -g NSServicesMinimumItemCountForContextSubmenu -int 7
killall Finder
```

This will allow up to six elements in the top level menu. Substitute `7` with the desired number.

Unfortunately, all elements from your submenu will be moved up, not just the MacVim one.