# How Do I associate all files with Emacs?

Tags: emacs

I'd like to be able to open any file with emacs as a choice when I right click it, regardless of environment.

Comment: If you are looking for a general solution, the linked questions should help. If you have a specific version of emacs (or want to click to have /usr/bin/emacs open), please edit those details into the question so we can focus on this specific example.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that [this apple.stackexchange topic](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/15030/how-can-i-add-a-new-application-to-the-open-with-menu) covers how to add items to the "Open With" menu.